# Converting dbf to shp with QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, dbf

I want to transform dbf to shapefile with QGIS. I see the polygons in QGIS, but when I try "export", "save as", or from Toolbox "Extract/Clip by extent" - I see the clipped portion, but   the "save as", raises the error:

> Could not create layer  (OGR error: Can't create fields of type Binary on shapefile layers.)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Please [Edit] the Question to indicate where you've going to obtain the geometry, since dBase only supports character, integer, float, and date types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will take the tour first and if there is still a problem will add it to my question.